# creating a list with database values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print a list something like this....

> ```
> Catagory 01
>    subjects1   subjects4
>    subjects2   subjects5
>    subjects3   subjects6
>
> Catagory 02
>    subjects1   subjects4
>    subjects2   subjects5
>    subjects3   subjects6
>
> Catagory 03
>    subjects1   subjects4
>    subjects2   subjects5
>    subjects3   subjects6
> ```

One category has its own subjects. At the moment I have the category id and created a query to get its category name and its owned subjects. this is the query that I have created..

```
$categoryIds = implode(',', $_SESSION['category']);

$q = "SELECT c. category_id AS ci, c.category_name AS cn, s.subject_name AS sn, s.subject_id AS si
FROM category AS c
INNER JOIN category_subjects AS cs ON cs.category_id = c.category_id
INNER JOIN subjects AS s ON s.subject_id = cs.subject_id
WHERE c.category_id IN ($categoryIds)";

$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q) ;
```

Above query gives every categories and it own subjects. Its like a multidimensional array. My problem is I tried to print this date something like above list... But can not get it to work..

$catID = false;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

```
echo '<div>';

if ( $catID != $row['ci']) {

    echo '<h3>Category 01: <span>' . $row['cn'] . '</span><span></span></h3>';
}

echo '<div class="container">';

    echo '<p>' . $row['sn']. '</p>'; // This subjects I need to display in a table with 2 columns..

$catID = $row['ci'];

    echo '</div>';

echo '</div>';
```

}

Is there someone to help me to this? Your ideas and comments are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't post code snippet as I dont have working environment, but here are tips.

You need to add category id and its name to order by clause to ensure, the records are not jumbled up.

1. Iterate over the result in a loop. Initialise a temporary variable (lets call it 'temp') to blank value.
2. To print the category name and id you can use temporary variable ('temp') which is used for comparing current category with the one being printed now. The temporary variable values changes once the category changes.
3. Subjects can be stored in an array ($subject_arr) and printed at the end when category changes inside loop. Later outside the loop check if subjects array has any contents, if yes print that to ensure nothing is left behind.
4. To print the subjects in column format (if your rows are fixed and columns are dynamic), you can divide the number of subjects by fixed number of rows you want and that will give you number of columns. (If there is remainder, just +1 number of columns)

Comment: Thanks for reply. your 1 and 2 steps are OK for me. 3rd and 4th steps are very confusing to me. I need to display subjects in a table with 2 columns. I tried it but can't get it to work.. Check I update answer with your 1st 2nd steps.

Answer (score 0):

How about first creating an array with the keys defined as followed

```
array("Category 1" => (
   array ( 0 => "subject1", "subject2", ...)),
      "Category 2" => (
   array ( 0 => "subject1", "subject2", ...)),
...);
```

one could do that by

```
<?php
    $r = array("0" => array("ci" => "1", "cn" => "Category1", "si" => "1", "sn" =>     "subject1"),
        array("ci" => "1", "cn" => "Category1", "si" => "2", "sn" => "subject2"),
        array("ci" => "1", "cn" => "Category1", "si" => "3", "sn" => "subject3"),
        array("ci" => "1", "cn" => "Category1", "si" => "4", "sn" => "subject4"),
        array("ci" => "2", "cn" => "Category2", "si" => "5", "sn" => "subject1"),
        array("ci" => "2", "cn" => "Category2", "si" => "6", "sn" => "subject2"),
        array("ci" => "2", "cn" => "Category2", "si" => "7", "sn" => "subject3"),
        array("ci" => "2", "cn" => "Category2", "si" => "8", "sn" => "subject4"));
        //[...]

    $arr = array();

    foreach($r as $entry) {
        $cat = $entry["cn"];
        if (!array_key_exists($cat, $arr)) {
            $arr[$cat] = array();
        }
        array_push($arr[$cat], $entry);
    }

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo $key."<br>";
        foreach($value as $infos) {
            echo "- ".$infos["sn"]."<br>";  
        }
        echo "<br>...";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to create an array of your subjects, grouped by the categories. Use your category_id as key for the grouping:

```
$subjects = array();
foreach($r as $subject) {
    if(!isset($subjects[$subject['ci']]) $subjects[$subject['ci']] = array();
    $subjects[$subject['ci']] []= $subject;
}

foreach($subjects as $category => $values) {
    echo $category."\n";
    foreach($values as $subject)
        echo '  '.$subject."\n";
}
```

If you really need this 2 column presentation you could split the array (e.g. use array_slice) and output one of each values each iteration.